# {MySQL} Error #1054 SQL seems fine(Trigger)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I get the error message:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'kaseamgc_store.plans.plan_id' in 'where clause'

This message is coming from my trigger which is a before insert trigger. It runs the following SQL:

```
UPDATE kaseamgc_store.store_players
   SET credits = credits + kaseamgc_store.plans.creditvalue 
 WHERE kaseamgc_store.plans.plan_id = kaseamgc_store.orders.plan_id
   AND kaseamgc_store.store_players.authid LIKE '%kaseamgc_store.orders.steam_id'
```

Now I ran the following SQL when I got the message (probably irrelevant):

```
INSERT INTO finish_order (txn_id, payer_email, mc_gross, steam_id, username,
                           password, date, provider, plan_id, forum_userid)
     VALUES ('info', 'email-adress', '1.00', 'STEAM_ID', 'TheUsername',
             'no-pass', 20150416, 'paypal', 1, 0)
```

I have removed some of the info, but it's irrelevant. Anyhow here's some screenshots of how the column `plans.plan_id` looks like in phpmyadmin:

[image]

I have 4 rows so I should have 1-4 in `plans.plan_id`

**Edit:** So i seem to be having this problem all over. I know it has something to do with the lines, but no idea why it's happening. It's where i want to compare two *variables. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is hard to tell if you have a question or if you resolved whatever issue it was. Also, you need to tag only those DBMS which are relevant. Are you using sql server or mysql? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Add the complete code of the trigger into the question.

Comment: @SeanLange I haven't solved it, sorry i was unclear. Using mysql server, was unaware that they aren't the same.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That is the complete trigger, something missing? besides the ; because you don't need to have it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating table `kaseamgc_store.store_players` and expect a column of table `kaseamgc_store.plans` (`plan_id`).

```
UPDATE kaseamgc_store.store_players -- table store_players
   SET ...
 WHERE kaseamgc_store.plans.plan_id .... -- table plans
```

That won't work. The correct solution depends on what you exactly need. A preceding assignment to a local variable might be a solution.